# Как правильно выбрать структуру таблиц для рабочих вахт?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, проектирование, таблицы

У меня есть множество таблиц такого вида (это рабочие вахты по 10 дней).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно выбрать структуру таблицы/таблиц для такого случая? Можно ли сделать таблицу таблиц или одну таблицу с фиксированным, но очень большим количеством столбцов? В БД я мало что понимаю, только некоторые основы.

Comment: Виктор SQL в часности MySQL  это Structured Query Language. Язык структурированных запросов. Так вот вам нужно определиться со структурой. Какие у вас есть данные, поля, в каком формате/типе. Исходя из данных можно будет проектировать таблицы. А у вас журнал. Что там? Как его используют? какие цели и задачи должна решать ваша база данных

Comment: *Как правильно выбрать структуру таблицы/таблиц для такого случая? Можно ли сделать таблицу таблиц или одну таблицу с фиксированным, но очень большим количеством столбцов?* 1 таблица. 4 столбца (дата, смена, операция (?), значение), возможно, ещё синтетический ПК.

Comment: Не совсем понятна конечная цель всего этого - что Вы потом хотите с этими таблицами делать?
От этого концепция и подход к решению этой задачи будет зависеть.
И как уже было ранее сказано - у Вас больше журнал, чем таблица.
Конкретизируйте задачу, потому как "без понятного ТЗ получается ХЗ" ! ;-)

Comment: Хочу, чтобы я мог обращаться к определенной смене из программы по ключу (например, номер смены) и иметь доступ к данным каждого дня этой смены. Если сделать таблицу, в которой 100+ столбцов будет работать, но чутье мне подсказывает, что можно подойти к этому разумнее и более удобным способом